# How to convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates so we can solve multivariable integrals

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, jacobian

> By transforming to polar coordinates, prove $\int_0^{a/\sqrt{2}}\int_x^\sqrt{a^2-x^2}(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}dydx=\frac{\pi a^3}{12}$.

I know that I have to change the function using Jacobian discriminant. Once that is done I will be integrating the new function which will end in $drd\theta$ instead of $dydx$. 
The thing I can not figure out is how to change the limits from the Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates. Can someone please tell me how they can be found so I can solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: I replaced your image with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It might be helpful to draw the region described by the cartesian limits, and then see how $r$ and $\theta$ would vary in that region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch the first quadrant of $x^2+y^2\le a^2$, then shade the integration region. You'll see $0\le x\le\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}},\,x\le y\le\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ iff $0\le r\le a,\,\frac{\pi}{4}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$. So the integral is $\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}d\theta\int_0^ar^2dr$, which agrees with the required result.

Comment: How are you getting those limits for x and y? As in, what equations are you using to get those identities?

Comment: @EddieJames I'm just reading off the limits from the original problem. Note the constraint on $y$ implies $x^2+y^2\le a^2$.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say r and theta not x and y. My bad

Comment: @EddieJames As I said, draw the diagram. The minimum value for $y$ is the line $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$; the maximum is the curve $r=a$.

Comment: Ahh I got it thanks so much